# Proof that the sign of a sum of fractions is preserved under addition of a common integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

I am working through Apostol's Analytic Number Theory, and am doing some companion exercises. Specifically, I am reading solutions to the problem of demonstrating that specific $L(1, \chi)$ are not equal to 0.

As a reminder / for context:
$$L(1, \chi) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\chi(n)}{n}$$

Now the proof verification process tends to run something like so:
Let's take a trivial example and let $\chi$ be a nonprincipal character under multiplication $\mod{3}$

We then have the character table:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
\chi_1(n) & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\chi_2(n) & 1 & -1\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

so then plugging our values in we have, for any integer k:
$\chi(3k) = 0$
$\chi(3k + 1) = 1$
$\chi(3k + 2) = -1$
Which means:
$$L(1, \chi) = (1-\frac{1}{2}) + (\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5}) + ...$$
Since every parenthesis term is positive, the verification process is complete.

This seems to rely on an implied result, specifically that if 
$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} > 0$ then for any integer k:
$\frac{1}{n+k} - \frac{1}{m+k} > 0$ and if $\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} < 0$ then for any integer k $\frac{1}{n+k} - \frac{1}{m+k} < 0$.

This appears self evidently true, and I'm fairly certain follows directly from some kind of trivial result. Any explanation of what result that would be, would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just algebra. Assuming $n$ and $m$ are positive, if $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}>0$ then $\frac{1}{n}>\frac{1}{m}$.  Then $n<m$, so $n+k<m+k$.
Then $\frac{1}{n+k}>\frac{1}{m+k}$.

Comment: whelp... now that you put it *that* way